# How can I put together objects with the same id in a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the object:

```
object = [
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: "a",
        age: 20
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "b",
        age: 19
    }],
    [{
        id: 1,
        address: "something",
        email: "something@"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        address: "helpppp",
        email: "something"
    }]
];
```

And I want this:

```
object = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "a",
        age: 20
        address: "something",
        email: "something@"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "a",
        age: 19
        address: "helpppp",
        email: "something"
    }
];
```

Comment: Are these JSON objects?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do. Show your attempts as [mcve] and whats wrong with it - post relevant information to help us help you.

Comment: @brunns: that doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can export the object in JSON/python dict format rather than as a Javascript object, the following will work.
`pprint` is used as a convenience for formatting output.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


def combine_list_of_list_of_dicts(source):
    output = defaultdict(dict)
    for a in source:
        for b in a:
            output[b["id"]].update(b)

    return list(output.values())


source = [
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "a",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "b",
            "age": 19
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "address": "something",
            "email": "something@"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "address": "helpppp",
            "email": "something"
        }
    ]
]


result = combine_list_of_list_of_dicts(source)
pprint(result)
```

Gives

```
[{'address': 'something',
  'age': 20,
  'email': 'something@',
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'a'},
 {'address': 'helpppp', 'age': 19, 'email': 'something', 'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using a list of lists, you can just as easily store each dictionary in a a list, but if you have no control of that I would make the following suggestions:

1. The keys in your dictionary need to be quoted with either a single quote or double quote.
2. You can find the `id`s for your dictionary with the following code:
   `ids = set(sum([[y['id'] for y in x] for x  in object], []))`

This statement is a bit convoluted in that it uses list comprehension, `sum` (to get individual elements from a list of lists, and `set` to get unique `id`s. So the following should work for the example you've described:

```py
flat_object = sum(object, [])
ids = set(sum([[y['id'] for y in x] for x  in object], []))

merged_object = list()
for obj_id in ids:
    same = [x for x in flat_object if x['id'] == obj_id]
    merged = same[0]
    for x in same[1:]:
        merged.update(x)
    merged_object.append(merged)
print(merged_object)
```

```
# output
# [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'age': 20, 'address': 'something', 'email': 'something@'}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'age': 19, 'address': 'helpppp', 'email': 'something'}]
```